# What typo am I making? (/testfor)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command block connected to a hopper clock that checks for a named Ender Pearl like so:

```
/testfor BrokenRobot_ {Inventory:[{id:"ender_pearl",Unbreakable:1,Damage:0,Count:1,Slot:9,tag:{display:{Name:"Name"}}}]}
```

When I `/give` myself the same item with the same NBT data, and put it in the top-left inventory slot (I'm pretty sure that's slot nine...) it says:

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using NBT matching in Minecraft, it only checks for the tags you list. Limiting your NBT match to the bare minimum works best. In your example, the `Unbreakable` and `Damage` tags are not needed, they don't do anything for ender pearls in anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

Usually means that the game can't resolve an entity matching the target selector and data tag specified. I.e. `NULL` is not a valid UUID.

There are three issues with your command:

1. You are missing the "minecraft:" in front of "ender_pearl", in NBT data the "minecraft:" is not optional, unlike in commands.
2. The unbreakable tag should not exist on an inventory item that does not have durability.
3. Your values are missing the type indicator ("b" for byte, "s" for short, etc.), while this is often not an issue, some values do break if you don't use them.

The command I used is:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Count:1b,Slot:9b,Damage:0s,id:minecraft:ender_pearl,tag:{display:{Name:Name}}}]}
```

Comment: [`Unbreakable`](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#General_Tags) does exist for some items, but it doesn't actually do anything for Ender Pearls and does probably not exist unless it's set explicitly for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, I misspoke, I meant for inventory items without durability